# Difficulty understanding the solutions to $x'' = -\omega^2 x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

For some reasons involving physics, I'm supposed to consider the equation $x'' = -\omega^2 x$.

Normally, I would say the solutions are of the form $x = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$. But when $\omega = 0$, the equation degenerates to $x'' = 0$, which gives an entirely different set of solutions: $x = ct + d$.

What stumps me is how these two cases aren't in the same form. No matter what I try to do to the cosine (splitting it as sin + cos, writing it as complex exponentials, etc), I can't seem to get it in a form where plugging in $\omega = 0$ gets me a linear solution.

So my question is this: **If I were to prove that the solutions of $x'' = -\omega^2 x$ were exactly those of the form $x = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$, where and why would the case $\omega = 0$ be eliminated?** I'm familiar with the process of solving first-order diffeqs, but I've never actually gone through a proof with a second-order one.

Comment: You need $-\omega ^2$ for trigonometric solutions - at the moment the solution is $Ae^{\pm \omega t}$

Comment: Thanks, I'll go fix that. Although, the same phenomenon occurs when it's $+\omega^2$.

Comment: If you plug $\omega=0$ into your solution, you find that $x$ is constant, which is *a* linear solution. The reason why it does not span the entire solution set when $\omega=0$, is because the two solutions used to form the linear combination (for the general solution) have become linearly dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a linear solution you need to fix the boundary or initial conditions, for example $x(0)=p, x'(0)=q$

Then if $x''=-\omega^2 x$, your solution for general $\omega \neq 0$ is of the form $A\cos \omega t+B \sin \omega t$

Then we have $A=p, \omega B=q$ so the solution is $$x(t)=p\cos \omega t+\frac q{\omega}\sin \omega t$$

Now using that $\lim _{\omega\to 0} \frac {\sin \omega t}{\omega}=t$, the limit as $\omega \to 0$ is $p+qt$

---

Let's try the case $x(0)=p, x(1)=q$ from which we derive $A=p$ and  $B=\frac {q-p\cos \omega}{\sin \omega}$ so that $$x(t)=p\cos \omega t+\frac {q-p\cos \omega}{\sin \omega} \sin \omega t$$

Taking the limit as $\omega \to 0$ gives $x(t)=p+(q-p)t$

---

Note that the case with $+\omega^2$ can be solved straightforwardly with exponentials and limits, or by using the alternative form of solution $x(t)=A\cosh \omega t+B\sinh \omega t$ which is wholly analogous to the trigonometric case with the usual adjustments for the hyperbolic functions.

Comment: Actually, the general solution for $x''=-\omega^2x$ is $A\cos\omega t + B\sin \omega t$ only if $\omega\neq 0$, when the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2 + \omega$ has $2$ distinct roots. If $\omega=0$, then $p$ has a double root and the general solution changes to $(A+Bt)e^{\lambda_0 t}$ where $\lambda_0$ is the double root. Since $\lambda_0=0$ in this particular case, that simplifies further to $A+Bt$.

Comment: This definitely explains how a linear solution can arise with particular boundary conditions, and it's satisfying in some ways, but there's still something troubling me: you say the general solution is $A \cos (\omega t) + B \sin (\omega t)$. But that's still not true for $\omega = 0$. I guess I was looking for a derivation that makes it clear why things break there. Perhaps there's a division by $\omega$ or by $x''$ that shows up somewhere.

Comment: @HenrySwanson In the form for $x(t)$ with the boundary conditions there is a division by $\omega$. By "general solution" I mean for general boundary conditions and general $\omega$. $\omega = 0$ is a special value, and what I have shown is that the solution for this special value is compatible with the limit of the general case, and can be derived from the general case as a limit.

Comment: @HenrySwanson With any boundary conditions, and physically plausible circumstances, you will find that a similar thing happens.

Comment: @5xum See my comment to OP on what I mean by "general". I have taken the question to mean "how is the changed form of the solution when $\omega=0$ compatible with the form of the solution in the general case when $\omega \neq 0$?" This is a question which puzzled me (also for the discrete case of recurrence relations), and which doesn't seem to be much discussed.

Comment: The second example really made it click. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The point is that $0$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial 
$\lambda^2 + \omega^2$ when $\omega = 0$.  For more on this, you might try
[this page of mine](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/coco/coco.html)